# NSDate to String with TimeZone Offset

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I've the following code

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
dateFormatter.calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)

dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
```

It produces date in the following format:
**2015-08-06T15:44:49+0000**
But I want it to be in the following format **2015-08-06T15:44:49+00:00**

As you can see the offset needs to b **+00:00** instead of **+0000**

Comment: Try with "ZZZZZ" (five times) instead of "Z"

Comment: That's what I got. "2015-08-06T16:00:39Z"

Answer (score 7):

You need to use "xxx" instead of "Z".

edit/update **Swift 3 or later**:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxx"
dateFormatter.string(from: Date())  // "2019-03-22T14:36:07+00:00"
```

If you need some reference you can use this:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thank you!